# Mixed one_hot and float input

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, keras, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to train model of LSTM layers data of timeseries of categorical (one_hot) action(call/fold/raise) and time. 
So example time series of 3 rounds where player 2x called and then folded.

```
  #Call  #0.5s    # Call    #0.3s   #Fold, 1.5s

[[[1,0,0], 0.5], [[1,0,0], 0.3], [[0,1,0], 1.5]]
```

The categorical array of call/fold/raise cannot be processed by the first layer (LSTM) and I cannot use simple Embedding layer because of the non-categorical time.

First layer - 
model.add(LSTM(500, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(3, 2)))

I have tried to change the input_shape, but nothing worked for me. 
Any ideas how to represent one_hot and float in once input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply concatenate, no need for embeddings as your one-hot encoding isn't of too high dimensionality and one-hot is an embedding in itself.

So I would try sequences of vectors:

```
[[1,0,0,0.5], [1,0,0,0.3], [0,1,0,1.5]]
```

and the LSTM or any layer that you'll use will figure out that the first 3 values mean the action and the last is something else (the time), don't worry about that.

```
model.add(LSTM(500, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(3, 2)))
```

should work.

Comment: Let's say I had two categorical variables (`cat1` and `cat2`) and one continuous variable (`cont`). One-hot `cat1` is 4-d, and one-hot `cat2` is 3-d. `cont` is obviously just a scalar value. If I were to concatenate: x=`[cat1; cat2; cont]`, would the network learn that the first 4 values represent `cat1`, the second 3, `cat2` and the last `cont`?

e.g.
`cat1_1 = [1,0,0,0], cat2_1 = [0,1,0], cont_1 = [0.3]`
`cat1_2 = [0,0,0,1], cat2_2 = [1,0,0], cont_2 = [0.8]`
`x_1 = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.3]`, `x_2 = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0.8]`

Comment: That's exactly what it will do, it doesn't really matter for the network which means what... They're just numbers and it will learn what weight to assign to each input :-)